# How to obtain java repositories having maximum number of stars and less than 100 commits

Tags: google-bigquery, github-archive

I am currently trying to obtain the top 100 java repositories having maximum number of stars and less than 100 commits using GitHub Archive and BigQuery. Could you please help to come up with a query for this purpose.

The initial query I have written to obtain the top 100 records for Java language as follows:

```
SELECT repository_name
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE repository_language = 'Java' 
AND PARSE_UTC_USEC(repository_created_at) >= PARSE_UTC_USEC('1996-01-01 00:00:00') 
AND PARSE_UTC_USEC(repository_created_at) < PARSE_UTC_USEC('2015-05-30 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY repository_name
LIMIT 100
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Add a `HAVING` clause to put a condition on the *group*:

```
SELECT repository_name
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE repository_language = 'Java' 
AND PARSE_UTC_USEC(repository_created_at) BETWEEN PARSE_UTC_USEC('1996-01-01 00:00:00') AND PARSE_UTC_USEC('2015-05-30 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY repository_name
HAVING COUNT(*) < 100  -- Add this clause
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC -- Add this to make the LIMIT meaningful
LIMIT 100
```

I don't know if the `100` of the `LIMIT` is related to the `100` maximum commit count. If so, it's not needed. If not (and you actually want to limit the rows to 100) then add an ORDER BY to chose *which* 100 rows you want (rather than 100 random ones).

I also simplified the date range condition to a `BETWEEN`.

---

Although the above is valid SQL (tested OK in MySQL, Postgres, SQLServer and Oracle), in case bigquery can't handle order by `COUNT(*)` (as reported by OP), use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT repository_name, COUNT(*) commit_count
    FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
    WHERE repository_language = 'Java' 
    AND PARSE_UTC_USEC(repository_created_at) BETWEEN PARSE_UTC_USEC('1996-01-01 00:00:00') AND PARSE_UTC_USEC('2015-05-30 00:00:00') 
    GROUP BY repository_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 100
) x
ORDER BY commit_count DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply... i also need to include the count of stars that each repositary has obtain. how can i include it to the given answer.

Comment: That's a separate question: Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I think we should move COUNT(*) to the select statement and use the alias in the order by statement. Otherwise the query does not work.

Comment: @user2475467 although it works as-is for all mainstream SQL databases, I've added the subquery version as you suggested.